# Remove a commit and its history to avoid hook configured in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have typed a wrong message in the commit and pushed to my remote branch when hook configured is turned off. But however I need to change the commit message and push to the remote branch. When I amend and push the code to the branch it sit's on top of the wrong message commit. I need to remove that commit from the history and replace the latest commit with correct message in remote.

Correct commit message: ticket #123 my commit
Wrong commit message: my wrong commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

Hard Reset your local branch and do

`git push --force origin yourbranchname`

That will rewrite the history.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to correct the commit message you can use `git commit --amend -m 'the new message'` and `git push -f`. It will replace the last commit message and not on top of the wrong message.

If you don’t want the whole last commit, you can switch to the branch and use 
`git reset --hard HEAD~` and `git push -f`.